# Partitions disappered automatically in my windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

There was a windows update 2 days before which got installed automatically. Today when I was using my computer suddenly my document editor got closed saying file not found to save in that location. So when I wen to my PC and to my shock I cannot see other drives than C drive.

Like this:

[image]

I went to disk management, to my surprise I cannot see the partitions there too

[image]

Comment: Assign drive letter to the partitions : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/79064-change-assign-drive-letter-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it had anything to do with the update. If the error appeared 2 days after the update. Where were the additional drive letters? On the same HD? A second one? Or maybe network folders?

If it was on the same HD - although it doesn't sound/look like it - it must be one of the three partitions/volumes behind the C-Drive. To mount the partition and assign a drive letter you can:

- Right-click the volume
- Click Change Drive Letter
- Click the Add button.
- Choose from a list of available drive letters. (You might not want to use A or B, which have historically been reserved for floppy drives and can sometimes confuse older software.)
- Click OK

If you have two Harddisks and one of them disappears during operations and only comes back after several reboots you should make a backup, either the Harddisk or s.th. on the mainboard (HD controller etc.) seems to be faulty.

Comment: Mine has SSD + Hard Disk C drive is SSD and remaing are regular hard-disk. I restarted the PC several times and it worked.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM Ok, if you have two Harddisks and one of them disappears during operations and comes back after several reboots you should make a backup, either the Harddisk or s.th. on the mainboard (HD controller etc.) seems to be faulty.